# Scala compiler never ending compilation

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I noticed my Scala IDE consuming all the available CPU... I tried to compile the project via SBT from the command line and I got the same situation.

How can I get to know what's going wrong? Is there a way to find out what file or class/object/trait is being compiled?

I'm getting the same issue in 2.10.2 and 2.10.4-RC1

Comment: Can't you use `–verbose` command line flag?

Comment: can you tell e how can I get a more verbose SBT while compiling?

Comment: I found how to do it... just added scalacOptions += "-verbose" in my build.sbt

Comment: Sorry, I'v been away for some time. Nice. If it's help you, and question is answered, you'd better note it somewhere, or I can post an answer, which you can accept. It will prevent people from wasting time, trying to answer it again.

Comment: Have you tried removing parts from your code to pinpoint which part causes the problem?

Comment: Of course I did.. and I found out the problem is due to importing a library from Slick 2.0 called heterogenous.syntax. I also got a contact with the Slick developing team in order to give'em some code to investigate on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was due to importing a library from Slick 2.0 called heterogenous.syntax. I also got a contact with the Slick developing team in order to give'em some code to investigate on.